# Convert Excel row to a single text file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate a text file for an Excel spreadsheet. However, the number of columns and rows is unknown in advance, and the format needs to be fairly specific. For example, given the following Excel format:

```
ID1 | ID2 |ID3
97  | 12  | 47
08  | 09  | 54
17  | 46  | 07
```

The output text file (single text file) would read as follows:

```
97,ID2:12;ID3:47
08,ID2:09;ID3:54
17,ID2:46;ID3:07
```

Is there a simple way to do this using VBA?

Presently I tried below a macro:

```
Sub WriteToTextFile()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    iLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Open "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt" For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        For j = 1 To iLastCol
            If j <> iLastCol Then
                Print #1, "ID1: "; Cells(i, j),
            Else
                Print #1, "ID2: "; Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
    Shell "notepad.exe ""C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

By using the above macro, I will get the output as mentioned below:

```
ID1: Col1     ID1: Col2     ID1: Col3     ID4: Col4
ID1:  1234567890            ID1: AJAY     ID1:  70      ID4:  72 
ID1:  1234567890            ID1: AJAY     ID1:  71      ID4:  73 
ID1:  1234567890            ID1: AJAY     ID1:  72      ID4:  74
```

But I need output as stated below:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1234567890,ID2: AJAY,ID3: 70,ID4: 72 
1234567890,ID2: AJAY,ID3: 71,ID4: 73
```

Please help me!

Comment: Yes, there is a relatively simple way to do this. However, SO is not a free coding service (and certainly is a not a paid one!). You will get a better response if you show what coding you have tried already, and explain how these results different from what you want/expect.

Comment: As I said I am inexperienced with VB. Please help me!

Comment: As @AJD indicated, you'll get a better response if you show what coding you have tried already, and explain how these results are different from what you want/expect. You'll also want to describe what research you've done so far. An advanced knowledge of VB.NET isn't required for this information.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [ask] and 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to ajust the output part a bit how you generate each line:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteToTextFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better by its name: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Open "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt" For Output As #1

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        Dim OutputLine As String

        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To LastCol
            If iCol = 1 Then 'first column (is different)
                OutputLine = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            Else 'append other columns
                OutputLine = OutputLine & "," & ws.Cells(1, iCol).Text & ": " & ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            End If
        Next iCol
        'Debug.Print OutputLine
        Print #1, OutputLine 'output the full line to the text file
    Next iRow

    Close #1
    Shell "notepad.exe ""C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt""", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

This will output

```
97,ID2: 12,ID3: 47
08,ID2: 09,ID3: 54
17,ID2: 46,ID3: 07
```

if the source data was
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using it!

Comment: In the output file ROW headings are missing.

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question. Please ask a new question for that and show what you have tried to accomplish that. This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Once again thanks for helping me. Refer my question and output, wherein I requested ROW headings.

Comment: Well in your first example there is no header. Then you mix up `,` and `;` in your example so it is pretty much unclear what you actually want to do. Anyway this answer shows how you would do it in principle and you should be able to improve it yourself. Again this is no code writing service where you can put your requests and get a code for free. But we can help you to accomplish your task if you show your effort and what you have tried. So please try to add the headers yourself and if you get stuck or errors ask a question to what you have tried.